# retrieving installation wizard's exit code to understand what button user pressed with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have some PowerShell scripts that launch an uninstall wizard. After the wizard I have some code to clean things up. I don't want to execute that code if the user presses the Cancel button on the wizard. The only way I know from (other uninstall wizards) what the user has pressed is by inspecting the ExitCode like so:

```
$fileArg = "/q";
$proc = Start-Process "C:\Program Files\erl-23.2\Uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList $fileArg -PassThru -Wait;
$proc.ExitCode;
```

The problem is that this particular uninstall.exe gives me the same exit code of 0 regardless if the user presses Next and uninstalls or if they press the Cancel button. I cannot tell the difference. Other uninstall wizards give me 1 when the Cancel button was pressed and other values if something else happens.

Is there some other way to know what button the user has pressed or at least tell the difference between the Cancel button and all other actions?

Comment: Which installation wizard are you using?

Comment: This is Erlang's uninstallation Wizard. How can I tell what installation wizard they are using?

Comment: Just forget the wizard and query some "registry key/folder/wmi" that should have been removed upon successful uninstall...